# How can I intercept property accesses in Groovy with ProxyMetaClass?

Tags: groovy

The ProxyMetaClass and Iterceptor classes for intercepting arbitrary Groovy method calls is well documented.  Is there also a way to intercept property accesses?  When I try to do this by intercepting "getProperty", I still get the error message:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: foo

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about the use-case that you're trying to solve, but likely you want one of either [propertyMissing](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing) or [getProperty (or maybe invokeMethod)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getProperty).

The first will let you intercept property requests when they don't actually exist on the object:

```
class Person {
    def name = "Ted"
    def propertyMissing(String name) { "my $name" }
}

def p = new Person()
assert "my address" == p.address
assert "my email" == p.email
assert "Ted" == p.name // property isn't missing
```

The second will let you intercept all property requests, even for defined properties:

```
class Person {
    def name = "Ted"
    def getProperty(String name) { "my $name" }
}

def p = new Person()
assert "my address" == p.address
assert "my email" == p.email
assert "my name" == p.name
```

If you're working with an existing class, you can either subclass it with one of these methods, or else add these methods to the metaClass:

```
String.metaClass.getProperty = { String name ->
    return "String's property $name"
}

assert "String's property foo" == "".foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be correct. Try some of the recipes [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class).

Clutching at straws: is the object you're calling methods on really of the class you've metaprogrammed? Sometimes due to polymorphism, you're not using the class you think you are.